# BufferedWriter turns String into symbol in txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I want to write some string to my txt but always write a symbol like this in txt file :

> ਰ

here's the code to write the txt file:

```
public static void writeToTxtTargetData(String cry) throws Exception {
    String target = "0";

    //check the label for target
    if(cry.equals("Neh")){
        target = "0";
    } else if(cry.equals("Owh")){
        target = "1";
    } else if(cry.equals("Eh")){
        target = "2";
    } else if(cry.equals("Eairh")){
        target = "3";
    } else if(cry.equals("Heh")){
        target = "4";
    } 

    //System.out.println(target);
    //write target to .txt
    try {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/initialTarget.txt");
        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append(target + "\n");
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and even when i fix the file manually into normal number like '0', and i read it using BufferedReader, it always read it as a symbol like this:

> ÿþ0

here's the code i'm using to read the file:

```
private void DefineCluster() throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test/initialTarget.txt"));
    target = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String line = "";
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        target.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }
    in.close(); 
}
```

Comment: code is not the problem, writing and reading both work fine for me

Comment: before i run that read and write function, i also use the same method on the same process/class to write and read huge data, but the results are fine, no weird characters, is using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter on huge data causing overload for the next use?

Comment: Try this without reading writing the huge data. See if this problem still occurs.

Comment: the problem still occure, maybe because i declared BufferedReader in and BufferedWriter bw twice on different function then i change the name in one of the function like  this BufferedReader an & BufferedWriter aw, and it goes normal. What makes me confuse is i didnt declare the  BufferedReader & BufferedWriter as global variable, but if i change the name varaible it effects  the system, idk what happen tho